# Ruby on Rails: Cucumber: how do I turn off the database cleaner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The system I'm testing is complex enough where writing separated test cases would be a huge waste of time and resources. So, I need my tests to build off each other.

But, for example, whenever I got User.new in one of my step definitions, once the scenario is done, the User is removed from the DB.

How do I keep all my information... unless I force a db:test:prepare?

This is my env.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../config/environment')

require 'cucumber/formatter/unicode' # Remove this line if you don't want Cucumber Unicode support
require 'cucumber/rails/world'
require 'cucumber/rails/active_record'
require 'cucumber/web/tableish'
require 'cucumber/rails/rspec' 
require 'rake'



require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara/session'
require 'cucumber/rails/capybara_javascript_emulation' # Lets you click links with onclick javascript handlers without using @culerity or @javascript
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'database_cleaner/cucumber'
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction

@subscription_plan = Factory(:subscription_plan)
@subscription_plan.save!

Capybara.default_selector = :css
Capybara.default_wait_time = 2
Capybara.javascript_driver = :culerity
Capybara.current_driver = :culerity
Capybara.default_host = "cucumber.test.com" #for Rack::Test
Capybara.app_host = "cucumber.test.com" #if Capybara.current_driver == :culerity

Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In features/support/env.rb should be a line:

```
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Set that to false, and your database truncation *should* cease.

Edit: Since this failed, try adding the tag @no-txn to feature files that require data to persist; it seems like this is a reserved tag used by Cucumber to cause scenarios to not be wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: I added my env.rb file. My DB is still missing data ... le boo. T_T

Comment: Try adding the tag @no-txn to feature files that require data to persist; it seems like this is a reserved tag used by Cucumber to cause scenarios to not be wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: Just noticed the lines in your env.rb file relating to DatabaseCleaner... try commenting them out (the lines such as "require 'database_cleaner'", etc.

Comment: I'm currently running cucumber-rails 0.4.1. Neither setting use_transactional_fixtures to false, nor tagging scenarios with no-txn prevents clean from being called within the hook.

Comment: @TheLindyHop Im having a similar problem as you. I attempt to turn off fixtrues using 'Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false' in order to run Selenium integration tests and it does not work. I have been stuck here for a couple of days. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Just adding here that none of these solutions actually work. Cucumber -v=1.2.3

Answer (score 6):

Having your tests build off each other is a terrible idea, because it means each test can't stand on its own, and makes your tests leak state (which gives lots of false test results). If your tests can't start from a clean slate, make them more atomic.

As things stand now, you're not really testing your system properly, judging from your description.

Comment: To clarify on this, have your test reuse previous step definitions, not tests

Comment: Agreed - I'm afraid that, "The system I'm testing is complex enough..." is a justification. If you need your database seeded with certain data (to save inserting data all the time) use the de-duplication tools available in Cucumber, such as the `Background` definition, or load your database with a known set of data before the Scenarios run. Also, if you think your tests should build off one another, it's a symptom that one test starts from the state at which the previous one left off. There's ways to simulate application state in Cucumber - the test themselves should always be stateless.

Comment: @normalocity: Couldn't have put it better myself. :) Except I think you meant "rationalization", not "justification".

Comment: Uh, yes. That's precisely what I meant. :P

Answer (score 2):

Just remove

```
gem 'database_cleaner'
```

from your Gemfile.

And checkout [active_record](https://github.com/Paulche/cucumber-rails/blob/master/lib/cucumber/rails/hooks/active_record.rb) file if `NameError` exception occurred.

It is due to silent dependency of `cucumber-rails` gem from `database_cleaner` gem.

Answer (score 2):

> Database Cleaner also includes a null strategy (that does no cleaning
>   at all) which can be used with any ORM library. You can also
>   explicitly use it by setting your strategy to nil.

https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner as of Nov 12, 2013

Answer (score 1):

Try with @no-database-cleaner in your feature

Comment: This turn off database_cleaner only for scenario tagged that. This isn't turn off database_cleaner entirely.

Comment: There is solution for turning off entirely in the next my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was

```
# features/support/env.rb
# ...
Cucumber::Rails::Database.autorun_database_cleaner = false
```

It comes from the [GitHub README](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/blob/master/README.md).